# R CMD check - Non standard things in check directory

Tags: r, build

I am trying to build an `R` package and some of the examples do generate pdf files. Now while checking, `R` `CMD` gives a note saying that there are non standard things in check directory. I am not able to see them as the `R` `CMD` deletes after the successful checks (no error or warning). I have tried include `^.*\.pdf` in `Rbuildignore`. Any help?

Comment: I would avoid having examples writing files. I'd use `\dontrun`.

Comment: If the example needs to create a file consider using `unlink` to delete the file at the end of the example.  Keeping the whole example in a `\dontrun` environment would be a good option too.

Comment: Or give the generated files explicit temporary file names by using `tempfile()`.

Comment: Many thanks Roland, Peter and Dirk. That is a huge help.